# Pasar datos automáticamente de sap tx. CS12 a excel preparado

Tags: vba, macros, sap

Estoy creando una macro vba en excel para que coja la referencia de mi excel y saque de la transacción CS12 en SAP-gui los materiales de la que se compone la referencia, así como otros datos (las primeras cuatro columnas) y los vuelque en mi hoja excel.
He conseguido copiar el script de SAP y crear el código vba con lo que me llega a abrir la transacción CS12 y seleccionar las cuatro columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que he usado y funciona hasta la selección de columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de aquí necesito el código vba y añadir para que se copie la selección y la pegue en el excel que tengo preparado

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [código para importar datos de la transacción CS12 a excel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/604464/c%c3%b3digo-para-importar-datos-de-la-transacci%c3%b3n-cs12-a-excel)

Comment: Vuelves a preguntar lo mismo que ya hiciste en otro post. Y además vuelves a poner imágenes con código saltándote las recomendaciones de otros usuarios en las que te indican cómo preguntar y cómo desarrollar tus preguntas.